# Ubuntu 14.4 LTS dvd problems

Tags: dvd

My dvds will not play.  I did "sudo apt-get install libdvdread4" and still nothing.  What else can I do?

Comment: After installing libdvdread4, what else did you do? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: I tried to play a movie and it shows on the menu but will not play. I had did it before and it worked. But I didn't write down what I put in the terminal to check for all the dvd drivers before I installed libdvdread4.

Comment: So you did not run the script that is mentioned, after installing libdvdread4 ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: I ran "sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh" then reboot.